# MongoDB shell: Run command asynchronously?

Tags: mongodb

Lately I have found I have to do a lot of long running operations like:

```
db.whois.find({"basic.last_updated":"1970-01-01 00:00:00"}).forEach(function (doc) {
  var parts = doc._id.split('@');
  doc.basic.last_updated = parts[1];
  db.whois.save(doc);
})
```

That's fine but since the shell prompt doesn't return until it's complete I am finding I have to keep lots of shells open. Is there any way I can issue a command and send it async so that I can continue using the same shell? Maybe even get a little message when the process is done?

Comment: This is probably a job for your Mongo driver of choice.

Comment: bash scripting FTW. Also you can with shortcuts in temrinal send processes to the back and use the mongo shell multiple times in one window.

Comment: Suggest looking at the [Admin UIs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs) that are available .. perhaps one is a better fit for your use case.  @dbaseman's suggestion is good as well; if you are basically queueing up jobs that save their results back to the database, then a small script in language-of-your-choice would do the trick and be easily backgroundable.