# It seems like I can't do concurrent read/count operation in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, concurrency

I have a very large collection which contains tens of millions of documents, and when I do the following operation, it takes a very very long time before it returns.

```
db.collection1.find({'venue.name': 'KDD'}).count()
```

And before this operation completes, I want to do other read/count operations like following:

```
db.collection2.find().count()
db.collection3.find()
```

But both of them block (they return immediately when I don't do the first operation).

Is this reasonable? Aren't these operations all read-operation, why aren't them done concurrently by mongodb?

EDIT: mongodb version: 2.6.11

Comment: what version of mongo are you using?

Comment: @RobertMoskal v2.6.11

Comment: You seem to be using the `mongo` shell, in which **all** operations are "synchronous" and therefore "blocking". This is not the case for many "drivers" in which of course you can run operations concurrently. But not in the shell of course.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["MongoDB shell: Run command asynchronously?"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11150738/5031275)

Comment: @BlakesSeven You will find it's actually not the same question if you have read your linked question carefully.

Comment: How so? I see nothing to suggest why it isn't the same question. You are running in the mongo shell are you not?

Comment: @BlakesSeven Uh...I use a GUI tool called Robomongo, and I don't know whether it is the same with shell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109310/discussion-between-thuzhf-and-blakes-seven).

Comment: Robomongo works exactly the same as the shell, in fact it "embeds" the mongo shell functionally. If you want "async" methods then use a programming language with a driver that supports it.